# .emacs bankruptcy -- how to do it well

Tags: init-file

So, at this point my .emacs.d and files with it is older than a lot of people reading this question, and with packages, version changes, packages that have gone obsolete, and so on. It's a mess.  It's time to declare emacs bankruptcy again.

So, with all the new features and such, what's the best way to get a fresh start?

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. SE is for specific Q & A. You will likely get better help with such a broad question somewhere else.

Comment: It seems like a reasonably bounded question. How would you rephrase it?

Comment: It's not about rephrasing it. It's a great question. But it is a broad question.

Comment: "What's a good approach to .emacs bankruptcy" still seems to be a straightforward question.

Comment: It is straightforward - nothing unclear about it. That's not the point.